# Number of permutations of a set which contains 55 elements

Tags: permutations

I am to find the number of permutations of a set which contains $55$ elements and the permutations meet following requirements:
$$\forall_{i\in \{1, 2, ..., 55\}} f(i)\neq i \wedge f \circ f = id$$

Comment: You are counting the fixed-point free involutions in $S_{55}$? I don't think there are very many of them.

Comment: Try with 3 instead of 55.

Comment: Me neither but I really would like to see if there is a method of finding the solution

Comment: I tried but I think I don't know how to use the second requirement @CatalinZara

Comment: If, say, $f(1) = 2$, then what is $f(2)$?

Comment: $f(2) = 1$ according to the first requirement? @CatalinZara

Comment: Yes, $f(2)$ must be 1, but that's because of the second requirement $f(2) = f(f(1))=1$; with only the first requirement, you could have had $f(2) = 3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any permutation is a (unique) product of cycles that commute with each other. Since you want $f^2=id$, the only cycles allowed are transpositions. Since you want $f(i)\ne i$, all elements should appear in one transposition.

This requires taking the elements in pairs. As the number of elements, 55, is odd, there will always be an element missing; any $f$ with $f^2=\text{id}$ has a fixed point. Thus, no such $f$ exists.

When the number of elements is even, say $2n$ the pairing is obviously possible. The number of [such pairings is given by](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342071/number-of-possible-pairs)
$$
\frac{(2n)!}{2^n\,n!}.
$$
For $f^3=\text{id}$, one would have to work with triples instead of pairs: the only cycles that are allowable are triples. So the problem becomes in how many way you can divide your elements in groups of $3$. Of course if you still what $f$ with no fixed elements (which is good, because otherwise the combinatorics become more complicated), then you need the number to be a multiple of $3$, say $3n$, and the number of possible $f$ will be 
$$
\frac{2^n(3n)!}{3^n\,n!}.
$$
The "new" $2^n$ in the numerator accounts for the fact that for every group of 3 elements there are two possible 3-cycles.

Comment: Thank you! That's quite an interesting solution and it's very helpful.

Comment: That means that we need an even numbers of elements? What if the second requirement would be a bit different: $f\circ f \circ f = id$?

Comment: I have edited the answer.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: you may want to emphasize that for any group of three elements, there are two cycles that meet the condition $f^{3} = id$.

Comment: @CatalinZara: absolutely. So, do you agree that we need a further $2^n$ factor in the numerator, to account for the possible choices of $3$-cycles for each triple?